# Let user join an organic group during site registration

Tags: 7, organic-groups, users

I would like my users to be able to select a preexisting Organic Group to join when they are registering to use my site. Is this possible? How should I do this?

I already have the groups set up, and the permissions are set so that so that non members can 'Subscribe to group (no approval required)'.

Comment: I have found another post for the same. You can review http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69455/select-organic-group-on-the-user-registration-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organic groups register  7.x-2.2 was already installed.

I worked out that my problem was that while I had created a content type which in the Organic Groups tab I set to be an OG ' Group', I had not created a second content type to be the Group Content for that group. By following [the D7 OG instructions on this](https://drupal.org/node/2014781) I was able to add a field in the user account settings to reference the Group I had created.

It appears to me that for each Group type and there must be a second content type which is designated to be 'Group Content' for that group.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable the module:

Organic groups register (Allow subscribing to groups during the user registration)

Answer (score 0):

You could set group audience field in you user entity
first go to admin/config/group/fields page and choose "user" in your bundle select list
then click the add field button now you added the group audience field in your user profile form.
Please see the image for configuration
[image]