# Allow user to join group during registration

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I am using D7 with Organic groups and Organic groups register. I have created the groups and when viewing a group node the link to 'Request group membership' is visible and working.

I wish a user to be able to select a group to join when registering to use the site. I have been unable to get this to work despite lots of attempts.

This issue has been discussed quite a bit as a number of people have problems with it. There is a [very short answer to a previous Drupal Answers question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69455/select-organic-group-on-the-user-registration-form) but it isn't very explicit. Judging by the lack of up-votes, I suspect other people have been unable to use the solution successfully.

This [comment in a thread about the issue](https://drupal.org/comment/7561949#comment-7561949) discusses the steps, but lots of people, myself included, have been unable to get this to work. People in [another thread](https://drupal.org/node/1108884) are also having problems with this.

I am hesitant to create a duplicate question, but there seems to be a real need for this to be documented clearly in a way that people can follow.